# Where is Product getSmallImage method?

Tags: magento

I'm trying to override `getSmallImage()` method from Product mode but I can't find it, even searching in the entire Magento folder.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: I know that `getSmallImage()` is a getter of Product small_image attribute but I need to do extra stuff before set this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It is in Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product class, around line no. 117. Look file in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product.php

Comment: You mean `getSmallImageUrl`. I'm looking for `getSmallImage()` :(

Comment: Upss sorry for quick overlook. As you know `small_image` is product property and `getSmallImage` is magic function. This function is not defined anywhere. For all object property, there is getter magic function in Magento, like `getSku` etc. But what do you wanna do with this function, if you wanna change some behavior you may look on `getSmallImageUrl` function

Answer (score 0):

Luis. SmallImage is a  magento product attribute small_image.If you want get value of an attribute of product then follow below process.

```
$product /*product object */
```

if attribute  is small_image
then you can get value of small image value of product 
$product`->getSmallImage();`

Procedure is `getAttributecode()`

```
    First character of attribute is converted into upper case and 
underscore(_) make next letter in upper case
```

It is magento methodology